# Qt - drag move qgraphicitem don't work nice

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, scene

My simple code base on Qt standard example 'diagram scene'. MainWindow is most simply, only load custom scene. UI is make in graphic editor.
Drag and move graphic polygon work with right mouse button, left create new item. So?
I must double click to item for select it. And item need double click with no release last click when I want move item. Is full dizzy.

**Item code:**

```
BasicDiagramItem::BasicDiagramItem(QGraphicsItem *parent):
    QGraphicsPolygonItem(parent)
{
    drawCustomPoly();
}

void BasicDiagramItem::drawCustomPoly()
{
    QPainterPath path;
    customPoly << QPointF(0,50) << QPointF(50,0)
              << QPointF(0,-50) << QPointF(-50,0)
              << QPointF(0,50);
    setPolygon(customPoly);
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges, true);
    //setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemClipsToShape,true); //testowe

}

void BasicDiagramItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{

    QGraphicsPolygonItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

**Scene code:**

```
DiagramScene::DiagramScene(QObject *parent):
    QGraphicsScene(parent)
{

}

void DiagramScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    if(mouseEvent->button() != Qt::RightButton) return;

    BasicDiagramItem *item;
    item = new BasicDiagramItem();
    //item->setBrush()
    addItem(item);
    item->setPos(mouseEvent->scenePos());
    QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(mouseEvent);

}

void DiagramScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent);

}

void DiagramScene::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    QGraphicsScene::mouseReleaseEvent(mouseEvent);
}
```

This code is similarity to Qt example. I just only don't use mode for create different object, don't use custom menu and I don't draw arrows.

So, what am I doing wrong? Why apps have a bug with double-click?

Comment: Is there a question you meant to ask here?

Comment: Thx, I forget write directly questions. In my mind i have connections wrong running = questions about that. Now i edit post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, what i do wrong? Why apps have a bug with double-click?

I think this is the reason:

```
void DiagramScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
   if(mouseEvent->button() != Qt::RightButton) return;
```

Note that on a single-left-click, mousePressEvent() just returns without doing anything; that would explain why nothing happens when you single-left-click.  (On a double-click, OTOH, mouseDoubleClickEvent() is called instead, and since you have not overridden mouseDoubleClickEvent(), the QGraphicsScene::mouseDoubleClickEvent() method is called and handles the click there.

I think what you want to do instead is this:

```
void DiagramScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
   if(mouseEvent->button() != Qt::RightButton) 
   {
      QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(mouseEvent);  // call up to superclass
      return;
   }

   [...]
```

This way, QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(mouseEvent) can do the work of selecting the item that the user clicked on.

Comment: Thanks man! Im so stupid :D This work great. For future generations: example can mislead because example use 'naked' return when wrong button (but move items to) and next switch case for create different object. A bit dizzy. Again, thanks :)